# How do I make copy of spreadsheet and save it to specified folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm working with Google App Script. I am trying to:

1. Make a copy of a spreadsheet
2. Give the copy a particular file name, and
3. Save it to a particular folder.
4. Undo the changes made to the main sheet

We are wanting to use Google Sheets to make invoices for our company.  We did this through excel, but want to move to Google instead.  I am using the following code, but it's not actually renaming the file.  I'd also like to add the current date the copy was created if possible. **I'm clueless when it comes to coding, but was able to piece together things to make it easier for our mom & pop company.

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('Carolina Fireworks Order Form!C8');
  sheet.setNamedRange('CustomerName', range);
  var TestRange = sheet.getRangeByName('Carolina Fireworks Order Form!C8').getValues(); 
  Logger.log(TestRange); 
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1UdK90fEs3gkP4KZuUbmZbvvyVAW5ZMGw"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy('TestRange', destFolder); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this:

```
  const ds = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"E MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  let name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C8').getValue();
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy('TestRange', destFolder).setName(`${name}_${ds}`);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make the name for what the value is in c8? I have the customer name in C8.  I cannot seem to get that to change.  The date part works great!

Comment: oh and to open that spreadsheet after hitting the button I have on the screen?

Comment: There is a way to open the spreadsheet but it's really kind of a hack and I don't want to do it.  But I did add the value in C8 to the name.

Comment: A hack??  Hmm.  I was able to get this to work with a slight modification.  It kept giving me an error.  Thanks!